# UserPrivilegedException, while creating a directory in HDFS as a specific user, through JAVA

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, file-permissions

I a'm using CDH 4.7. I am trying to create a folder in HDFS in /user/cloudera. But the UserPrivilegedException is thrown. Below is my code (#copied)

public static void main(String args[]) {

```
        try {

        UserGroupInformation ugi = 
                UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser("cloudera", UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser());

        System.out.println(ugi.getUserName());
        ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {

            public Void run() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("aaa");
                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera");
                conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "cloudera");


                FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

                fs.createNewFile(new Path("/user/cloudera/test"));
                Path path = new Path("/user/cloudera/Hbasesyntax.txt");

                FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(path);
                for(int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(status[i].getPath());
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then, I even tried accessing the file (Hbasesyntax.txt) which I -put through the terminal. But, not able to get the file information from that too. Am I missing anything.

Below is the exception thrown:

```
Feb 23, 2015 1:18:27 AM org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation doAs
SEVERE: **PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera via cloudera        cause:java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /user/cloudera
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /user/cloudera
at**   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:378)
    at   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createNewFile(FileSystem.java:647)
    at HDFSFileOperations.GetIntoFS$1.run(GetIntoFS.java:32)
    at HDFSFileOperations.GetIntoFS$1.run(GetIntoFS.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at     org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1    190)
    at HDFSFileOperations.GetIntoFS.main(GetIntoFS.java:21)
```

Comment: Hello Jack, I hope upto this time you must have discovered the reason of this problem. Would you mind sharing it with us. Actually we are facing this same issue.